# Improve performance of my ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying writing a query that gets all the `User` statuses, and the count of those statuses. My approach, however, is very expensive, and is taking a toll on the database by making tons of queries.

I'm still new to this, and want to refactor this code so it will stop timing out. Below is the code I have so far:

**User model:**

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationActiveRecordBase
  has_many :purchases
end
```

**Purchase model:**

```
# app/models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ApplicationActiveRecordBase
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Schema:**

```
# app/db/schema.rb
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean  "has_registered"
  t.boolean "has_unsubscribed"
end

create_table "purchases", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "item"
  t.integer "price"
  t.integer "user_id"
end
```

**Code that I want to optimize:**

```
status = Hash.new(0)
User.find_each do |user|
  status[check_user_status(user)] += 1
end

def check_user_status(user)
  if user.purchases.count > 0
    'purchased'
  elsif user.has_registered?
    'registered'
  elsif user.has_unsubscribed?
    'unsubscribed'
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the methods `register_for_account`, `purchase_something` and `has_unsubscribed` unless they are database columns then you should state so.

Comment: your schema.rb and model definition would really help :)

Comment: Do you have the option to add to the code? If possible, one approach would be to add an `enum :status` to your `User` model, that is updated when the user registers, purchases or unsubscribes. This would denormalize your database a little bit, but I think it would be a perfectly acceptable optimization, and would also make your code a lot clearer.

Comment: I'm not able to add to the model/code because this query is used as as an admin dashboard/reports.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could solve this problem with 3 queries and no iteration if you just did the following:

First, you have to keep a counter cache for purchases per user. Luckily Rails already have a very nice and elegant way of doing it. Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column.

So you would have to change the model:

```
# app/models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ApplicationActiveRecordBase
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :purchases_count
end
```

And then create a migration to create the counter column:

```
# db/migrate/000_add_purchases_counter_to_user.rb
def self.up
  add_column :users, :purchases_count, :integer, :default => 0

  User.reset_column_information
  User.all.each { |u| User.reset_counters u.id, :purchases }
end

def self.down
  remove_column :users, :purchases_count
end
```

After this rails will make sure to keep the purchases_count updated when new purchases are created of deleted.

Now you can use these 3 queries to retrieve the data you need:

```
purchased = User.count_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE purchases_counter > 0")
registered = User.count_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE purchases_counter = 0 AND has_registered=?", true)
unsubscribed = User.count_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE purchases_counter = 0 AND has_unsubscribed=?", true)
```

Comment: Or one query if you say things like `sum(case when purchases_counter > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as purchased, sum(case when purchases_counter = 0 and has_registered then 1 else 0 end) as registered, ...`. I'd guess that you'd be doing table scans anyway so you might as well do just one.

Answer (score 0):

Do each separately

```
ids =   Purchase.unscoped.uniq.pluck(:user_id)
status[:purchased] = ids.count 
ids = User.where.not(id: ids).where(has_registered: true).pluck(:id)
status[:registered] = ids.count
status[:unsubscribed] = User.where.not(id: ids).where(has_unsubscribed: true).count
```

Comment: The issues with this method is that a user should only have one status. If a user has purchased something, they should count as 'purchased', not both 'purchased and 'registered'.

Comment: This is a good approach from a performance perspective, but is not equivalent to the original code. For example, this will count someone who registered and purchased in both categories, but the original code will only count them in the `purchased` category.

Comment: @Andy Kwong I have edited the solution. Kindly check.

Comment: @AndyKwong did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest,

1. Add a user_status column of type integer to your User model.
2. Migrate data to the new user_status column from the has_registered and has_unsubscribed columns and purchases.count. For example, if purchases.count > 0 then their user_status is going to be 1. If has_registered then user_status is 0 ....
3. In your User model add:

   enum user_status: [ :registered, :purchased, :unsubscribed ]
4. Then you can query and get the count with:

   User.group(:user_status).count

This would return something like  {1=>3, 2=>1} where 1 is the user_status, in this case "purchased", and 3 is the count. So in this sample we have 3 users who have a purchased status and 1 user who has unsubscribed.

4. You could also do three queries instead with this approach.

   User.purchased.count

   User.registered.count

   User.unregistere.count